# Pandas groupby returning only one column of data

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm going about trying to learn pandas and was looking at a basic introduction to working with a [basketball dataset](http://neckbeardrepublic.com/screencasts/pandas-data-frames-part-1) the problem I was having was creating a new groupby dataframe. For instance he was creating the following which I was unable to view:

```
group_by_opp = data.groupby('Opp')

field_goal_per_team = group_by_opp.sum()[['FGA', 'FG']]

data[data.Opp == 'ATL']
```

His output is the following table:

[image: Correct dataset]

Where my output with the same code (having followed the same process) is the following table:

[image]

I'm hoping I just made some sort of syntactical error in my work, but was wondering if any of you guys could take a look and help me understand what I was calling and what exactly I had done incorrectly.

Thanks so much!
Matthew

Full code as requested:

```
import vincent
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

vincent.core.initialize_notebook()

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
columns = ['Rk','G','Date','Age','Tm','Home/Away','Opp','Win/Lose','GS','MP','FG','FGA','FG%','3P','3PA','3P%','FT','FTA','FT%','ORB','DRB','TRB','AST','STL','BLK','TOV','PF','PTS','GmSc','+/-']
data = pd.read_csv('kd2013.csv', names=columns)

del data['Rk']
del data['Home/Away']
del data['GS']
del data['Win/Lose']

group_by_opp = data.groupby('Opp')
group_by_opp.sum()

data.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 82 entries, 0 to 81
Data columns (total 26 columns):
G       81 non-null float64
Date    82 non-null object
Age     82 non-null object
Tm      82 non-null object
Opp     82 non-null object
MP      82 non-null object
FG      82 non-null object
FGA     82 non-null object
FG%     82 non-null object
3P      82 non-null object
3PA     82 non-null object
3P%     82 non-null object
FT      82 non-null object
FTA     82 non-null object
FT%     82 non-null object
ORB     82 non-null object
DRB     82 non-null object
TRB     82 non-null object
AST     82 non-null object
STL     82 non-null object
BLK     82 non-null object
TOV     82 non-null object
PF      82 non-null object
PTS     82 non-null object
GmSc    82 non-null object
+/-     82 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(25)
```

edit: Added on loading the data and adding the `data.info()` as requested.

Comment: You're going to have to show the output from `data.info()` and also the code showing how you loaded the data

Comment: Got it, I'll do that now.

Comment: Aha, your `data.info()` question made me realize what the error likely was (and `data.info()` is super helpful so thank you, I'll use that going forward! So for some reason in his CSV file (taken from '12-'13) it appears as though the numbers were default loaded into `pandas` as float64 objects, whereas in my CSV they are object's. The exception is the G column! Which is what we yield. I'll post the full results but I'm guessing that's the issue. Is there a reason that happened in his CSV file but not mine?

Comment: An added question; I looked for sort of a simple reference table for pandas for methods on the dataframe objects (like info()) is there a link you recommend that has all of them in aggregation?

Comment: [Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html) and specifically [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to my question was that my CSV file was importing everything as an object file rather than a float64 or int64;

I'm as of yet unsure why this is or how that ends up occuring. I suspect that because of the last row (which was "inactive" for most entries that normally yielded ints.) I wrote a simple function to convert each column I wanted to look at in vincent using:

```
def object_to_int(numbers):
    return int(numbers)
```

from there I applied the mapping function to the columns:

```
data['FG'] = map(object_to_int, data['FG'])
data['FGA'] = map(object_to_int, data['FGA'])
```

i noticed the functions were raising a value error because I couldn't int() on a string, why was that? duh, there was a column of inactives. so i trimmed that:

```
data = data[data.MP != 'Inactive']
```

and voila:

```
group_by_opp.sum()

G   FG  FGA
```

Opp
ATL 28  21  40

Comment: You don't need to call your function to convert to int, just call `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects

Comment: how does it handle errors such as the 'Inactive' case in this arrays example?

Comment: They become `NaN` which may or may not be what you want